# First result of foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to get Facebook urls from multiple websites. Some websites contain more than one link to Facebook, but only want to echo the first found link.

```
$html = file_get_html('URL');   
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
$word_fb = $element->href;
if ( (strpos($word_fb, "http://www.facebook") === 0) || (strpos($word_fb, "https://www.facebook") === 0) ){
echo $word_fb;  
}
```

What is the correct way to echo only the first found result in this foreach loop?

Comment: $element is an object you have to convert into array or break the loop after first echo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have an extra condition inside the `foreach` it might be easier to use `break;` once you have found the first match:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $word_fb = $element->href;
    if ( (strpos($word_fb, "http://www.facebook") === 0) || (strpos($word_fb, "https://www.facebook") === 0) ){
        echo $word_fb;  
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, you could simplify the condition by using regular expressions:

```
if (preg_match('#^https?://www.facebook.com#', $word_fb)) {
    echo $word_fb;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use break; command which stops current loop:

```
$html = file_get_html('URL');   
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
  $word_fb = $element->href;
  if ( (strpos($word_fb, "http://www.facebook") === 0) || (strpos($word_fb, "https://www.facebook") === 0) ){
    echo $word_fb;  
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `break;` in your `if` statement:

```
if ( (strpos($word_fb, "http://www.facebook") === 0) || (strpos($word_fb, "https://www.facebook") === 0) ){
    echo $word_fb;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with `break`.

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $word_fb = $element->href;
    if ((strpos($word_fb, "http://www.facebook") === 0) || (strpos($word_fb, "https://www.facebook") === 0)){
        echo $word_fb;  
        break; //exit
    }
}
```